# Using Kotlin Flow from Repository to generate a new Flow in View Model

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-flow

From repository I am getting a Flow<List< ViewLights >>

```
data class ViewLights(
val groupId: Long?,
val group: String?,
val groupType: String?,
val light: String,
val isTurnedOn: Boolean,)
```

This includes a list of lights with a light group information (e.g. 1 | Living Room | Room | Wall Light | true)

In the view model I want to use the information from the first flow to generate/update a second flow (LightGroupStatus) that will get the latest information.

```
data class LightGroupStatus(
val groupId: Long,
val groupName: String,
val groupLightsCount: Int,
val groupLightsCountOn: Int,)
```

This new flow should

- be filtered by the groupType (only "Room")

  e. g.

  _lightsAndGroups
  .map {lightsAndGroupsList ->
  lightsAndGroupsList.filter {
  it.groupType == "Room"
  }
- list the groups and the amount of lights (total number -groupLightsCount- and number of lights on -groupLightsCountOn-)

ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel 
class LightsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: LightRepository,
    private val lightUseCases: LightUseCases,
) : ViewModel() {

private val _lightsAndGroups: Flow<List<ViewLights>> = lightUseCases.getAllLights()
val lightsAndGroups = _lightsAndGroups

private val _lightGroupStatus = MutableStateFlow<List<LightGroupStatus?>> (emptyList())
    val lightGroupStatus = _lightGroupStatus.asStateFlow()
```

How can I fill _lightGroupStatus with the grouped information from _lightsAndGroups?

Comment: Do you actually need to publicy expose the cold flow `lightsGroupStatus`, and why have you duplicated the property with public and private versions when they return the exact same type and instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```kotlin
    val lightGroupStatus = lightsAndGroups
        .map { lights ->
            lights.filter { it.groupType == "Room" }
        }
        .map { lights ->
            lights.groupBy { it.group }
                .map {
                    LightGroupStatus(
                        groupId = it.value.first().groupId ?: 0L,
                        groupName = it.key.toString(),
                        groupLightsCount = it.value.size,
                        groupLightsCountOn = it.value.filter { x -> x.isTurnedOn }.size
                    )
                }
        }
```

Hope it helps!